# Run batch command in jenkins

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm running jenkins on windows 7 as a service.

I'd like to run a very simple job which will start my firefox. (for example)

I configured a free style project and set up the "Execute windows batch command" option.

Here i have tried to insert couple of command which they all failed.

Commands like "echo hello" or other native command working as expected.

But command like "explorer " - should open the mentioned directory, or "c:\firefox.lnk" (should open firefox) are not working.
The jenkins seems to be running but after while the job fails with an error.

How can i run these actions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the error that they fail with.

Comment: I don't have any error.

Jenkins keep running until i manually stop the job.

This is the output i see :

"
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Selenium2\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\Or\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson3311426922560007225.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Selenium2\workspace>explorer .
Build was aborted
Finished: ABORTED
"

Comment: In your case, the jenkin process run as service.  The newly launched process explorer/firefox etc may be available on system console. I install and run VNC as a service  to access the system console

Comment: And with the VNC could i connect the jenkins service ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782414/how-to-run-testng-tests-on-jenkins/31716581#31716581

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a path issue, check if the System user has 'explorer' in its path. (see http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.nl/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html)

Additionally: Windows 7 does not allow service processes to create a UI. See this other stackoverflow question: [Service starting a process wont show GUI C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798612/service-starting-a-process-wont-show-gui-c-sharp)

Comment: Great, that was the reason.
Do you know how can i run jenkins not as a service? there is any .bat file that i can run jenkins?
thanks.

Comment: OK, i run it with tomcat and the war file, and It's all working! thanks so much!