# How to run batch file on remote machine using Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to run a batch file(which is on remote machine) using Jenkins. I have IP address of remote machine and in my local machine I have Jenkins installed.

I am not able to access remote machine using Jenkins. I am able to run batch file locally.

Both remote and local machine are windows7.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help..

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/cjGPJ_sNjTk

[Run batch command in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504811/run-batch-command-in-jenkins)

Comment: thanks for your help. Google group link is not accessible for me

Comment: Can you please give me steps to configure Jenkins for remote batch file execution?

Comment: its in open google group("Jenkins Users") should be accessible to everyone, what are you getting after clicking on the link ?

Comment: It's giving "You are not authorised to make this request. The permissions may have changed or you may have been logged out. Please reload the page and try again."

Comment: seems like gmail login required, could you please make sure to login before hitting link ?