# Running jmeter through jenkins with maven/ant

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ant, jmeter

I want to run jmeter script(test.jmx) through jenkins with Maven or Ant, can anybody help me out on this. I don't have much knowledge of maven/ant so can anyone please provide me the exact steps which I need to perform to do this activity?

I have integrated performance plugin for jmeter reports as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking over the web prior to asking?

- [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) - for Ant. Besides under *extras* folder of your JMeter installation there is **build.xml** file which is Ant configuration file you can use as a template
- [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) - for Maven.

If you have freedom to choose, you may even go for simple [non-GUI command-line execution](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui). If you use Performance Plugin you may have to pass an additional argument to force JMeter to store its results in XML format like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t testplan.jmx -l results.jtl
```

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for overview of aforementioned and other JMeter test unattended execution options.

Comment: I know it might not be related to this question. Could you please help me on this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234661/how-to-email-html-report-of-jmeter-execution-via-jenkins-the-one-which-we-get-us

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitri has suggested, you really don't need Maven or Ant to run JMeter scripts from Jenkins. A simpler alternative is to create a batch file for executing JMeter scripts and then run that batch file via Jenkins.

Steps will be like this (assuming you have not setup Jenkins):

1. Create batch file for Jmeter script (refer to Dmitri comment and Link)
2. Install & configure Jenkins (yakiloo . com/setup-jenkins-and-windows/)
3. Call the batch file through Jenkins. You can find many threads on how to run a batch file via Jenkins. ([Run batch command in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504811/run-batch-command-in-jenkins))

Answer (score 0):

Even though you really do not need Ant/Maven, It is good to run JMeter tests through Ant. Because you will end up creating a batch file for your requirement - running the test, creating HTML report and charts etc from the result file.

For detailed steps on using Ant for Jmeter tests, I would advise you to check this site: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/