# how to email html report of Jmeter execution via Jenkins the one which we get using -e -o in command line?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, html-email, email-attachments

I want to integrate Jmeter with Jenkins for Functional and Performance testing. (Hope Jmeter is good for Functional testing and Performance both). Have created a Freestyle project with Necessary plugins, Performance, and Editable Email ones.

I am able to generate reports in Jenkins workspace using:

```
sh ./jmeter.sh -n -t jmx_path -l /workspace_path/result.csv -e -o /workspace_path/htmlReport
```

Also, able to attach index.html file in email. But the problem is it's not accessible as css and other related files are not there.

Please help me on this. Let me know if any other info is required from my end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because sending `index.html` only is not sufficient, you need to send [`content`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.4.1/bin/report-template/content) and `sbadmin2-1.0.7` folders as well so instead of sending index.html file you need to send the whole `htmlReport` folder

You can pack it like

```
sh 'zip -r /path/to/htmlReport.zip /workspace_path/htmlReport'
```

and then send the .zip file to the recipients of your choice

An easier option would be using [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) tool a a wrapper for your JMeter test, it has [online reports feature](https://gettaurus.org/docs/BlazemeterReporter/#Personalized-Usage) so you will only need to share the link