# In Jenkins - Windows Batch Command Not Working

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am trying to execute a window batch command in Jenkins, and it is not working. I have reviewed [Run batch command in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504811/run-batch-command-in-jenkins), but I couldn't fix from that post.

I ran the following command to copy a file to a new location and give it a new name:

```
copy /B "%my_home%\base\dist\proj*.war" "%my_home%\base\dist\wars\proj.war"
```

In my case, the source directory has a single file called proj123.war. The file is successfully copied the the target directory, but the name remains proj123.war rather than renaming to proj.war.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For 1) Your statement doesn't make any sense.

`copy /B "%my_home%\base\dist\proj*.war" "%my_home%\base\dist\wars\proj*.war"`

Say you have

`projA.war`
`projB.war`
`projC.war`

They will all get saved as `proj.war`, first A, then B, then C. So it will be over written. They won't get copied as individual files.

You also don't need the `/B`.

In the future, provide a detailed description of the error you're getting.

**EDIT:** Given the update the comment, the desired command would be.

`copy /B "%my_home%\base\dist\proj*.war" "%my_home%\base\dist\wars"`

This will copy all files that match `proj*.war` to the `wars` directory while keeping the original names.

Comment: Although I agree with your statement, this is not an answer

Comment: @Rik while i agree with your sentiment, i recently joined the community and i would have preferred to post a comment but i am unable to. So i created an answer in an attempt to get more information so i could try to help :) and i even explained how the copy works. He stated that the command worked fine on windows but it shouldn't have as he provided.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Also, JordanGS is correct my example was in error. It should have read: copy /B "%my_home%\base\dist\proj*.war" "%my_home%\base\dist\wars\proj.war". The result is that the original file called  "%my_home%\base\dist\proj123.war" is successfully copied to the target directory, BUT the name remains "proj123.war" rather than the desired "proj.war" (I have edited the post accordingly).

Comment: @TimClotworthy see update, if this has answered your question please flag it as the correct answer and upvote. If it does not please feel free to comment/clarify the issue :)

Comment: @TimClotworthy You're not changing the source name, you're creating a copy to `destination` with the name `proj.war`. If you want to rename the source file then you have to copy to the same directory and not a different one.

Comment: thanks for the response JordanGS but as originally said I am trying to "copy a file to a new location and give it a new name". I am not trying to rename a source file. YOu can absolutely copy to a new directory with a new name from a windows shell. It works fine in a windows shell. Its not working within the context of Jenkins is the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: What's the error from the `console` output? This works fine for me. What's your jenkins environment. Master alone or a master-slave? need more information to diagnose.

Comment: I am required to obfuscate the output slightly, but it is essentially: "..\base\dist\wars\proj123.war 1 file(s) copied." In other words, correct target folder, incorrect target name.